# Need something that is dishwasher safe that breaks down paraffin

Tags: organic-chemistry

I work for a company that has a lab where there work leaves a lot of dishes coated in paraffin. Today I learned that they wash these in a non commercial dishwasher to remove the stuff.... one issue they paraffin solidifies and gunks up the washer. They have been replacing these every few months or so. After talking with the lab staff, they expressed concern and are open to using an extra step to remove the paraffin before washing. What most of the internet has to say is obviously do not wash paraffin in a dishwasher. Feeling a little s.o.l here, does anyone know anything that could potentially help, so we can end the vicious cycle of dishwasher destruction.

Comment: Is this paraffin wax that is on the dishes? If so, then a wash with heptanes should dissolve it off. Collect the washing in a sealable bin for disposal.

Comment: In my previous lab, they used a lot of paraffin for making microscope slides. They kept the tools in an oven at 60 C to melt the paraffin and just let it drip off the tools. Everything was coated in newspapers to catch any paraffin that dripped off onto tables or the floor. So maybe you could try heating the dishes to about 60 C to melt off excess paraffin.

Comment: On edge, into a catch container, of course.

Comment: There are dishwashers made for using solvents in them. Tend to be pricy, but so it goes.

Answer (score 1):

This may be doable, [per a source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraffin_wax#:%7E:text=Paraffin%20wax%20is%20mostly%20found,%2C%20benzene%2C%20and%20certain%20esters.), to quote:

> Paraffin wax is mostly found as a white, odorless, tasteless, waxy solid, with a typical melting point between about 46 and 68 °C (115 and 154 °F).

So as a pre-treatment, try applying a jet of steam to facilitate the removal of the paraffin wax.

Comment: Even a heat gun as a first treatment. Or a lab oven (put a layer of aluminum foil on the bottom to catch the wax).